# Buttons and scrollbars stopped working in maximized windows

Tags: windows-10

I'm running Windows 10 Home 64-bit. All of a sudden, the minimize/restore/close buttons stopped working in maximized windows; additionally scrollbars don't work in maximized windows and sometimes web app buttons don't work in Chrome. I have a dialog "Restore pages?" in Chrome which I can't dismiss because that button doesn't work either, even if I unmaximize the window. This is rendering my PC practically unusable - help please? :)

edit: already tried rebooting, `chkdsk`, and `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`; if I reboot the problem goes away temporarily but within a minute it's back, as if some program that runs on startup is causing it but I don't know which...

Comment: You have run DISM so now you need to run a Windows 10 Repair Install and start with Keep Everything.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Save.
Create a USB Windows Installation key and then run Setup on the USB Key. 
This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Comment: I don't have a USB drive to use, is there another way to do this?

Comment: You can use a USB Key (32 GB key) and that will work just fine. USB keys are easy and inexpensive to purchase.  You can also just download the Media Creation Link directly and Run in place. That works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Windows settings to find out what programs had been updated recently and it looks like Slack had been updated. I don't use Slack anymore and so I uninstalled it, which solved my problem.